# Перегрузка оператора присваивания C++ без использования strcpy

Tags: c++, строки, перегрузка-операторов

Изучаю C++. Буду очень признателен за любую помощь. Не нашел ответа на сайте. Нужно переопределить оператор присваивания. Сейчас сделано так:

```
    Stroka& Stroka::operator=(const Stroka& s)
{
    strcpy(str, s.str);
    return *this;
}
```

Но нужно, чтобы он работал с использованием конструкции вида - без использования strcpy:

```
void Stroka::kopir(char *first, char *second)
{
    while (*second) {
        *first++ = *second++;
    }
    *first = '\0'; // символ перевода строки, = \n
}
```

Полный код программы взят из учебного примера, выглядит следующим образом:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Stroka {
    char str[80];
public:
    // Конструктор класса 
    Stroka(char*);
    Stroka(const char*);
    // Конструктор класса 
    Stroka() {}
    Stroka(const Stroka&); // Конструктор копирования
    Stroka& operator=(const Stroka&); // переопределение/перегрузка операции присваивания
    Stroka& operator+(const Stroka&); // переопределение операции сложения
    int operator==(const Stroka&); // переопределение операции сравнения
    void vvod();
    void vyvod();
    void kopir(char *first, char *second);
}
;

Stroka::Stroka(char *string)
{
    strcpy(str, string);
}

Stroka::Stroka(const Stroka& s)
{
    strcpy(str, s.str);
}

Stroka& Stroka::operator+(const Stroka& s)
{
    strcat(str, s.str);
    return *this;
}

// метод класса Stroka
int Stroka::operator==(const Stroka& s)
{
    if ((strcmp(str, s.str)) == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void Stroka::vvod()
{
    cout << "Введите текст:" << endl;
    cin >> str;
}

void Stroka::vyvod()
{
    cout << "Вывод текста на экран:" << endl;
    cout << str << endl;
}

Stroka& Stroka::operator=(const Stroka& s)
{
    strcpy(str, s.str);
    return *this;
}

void Stroka::kopir(char *first, char *second)
{
    while (*second) {
        *first++ = *second++;
    }
    *first = '\0'; // символ перевода строки, = \n
}

int main(int)
{
    setlocale(0, ""); // установить русскую локацию
    Stroka s1;
    s1.vvod();
    Stroka s3;
    s3.vvod();
    Stroka s4;
    s4 = s1;
    Stroka s5;
    s3.vyvod();
    s5 = s1 + s3 + s4;
    s5.vyvod();
    if (s1 == s5)
        cout << "строки s1 и s5 равны";
    else
        if (s1 == s4)
            cout << "строки s1 и s4 равны";

}
;
```

Comment: А проблема в чем? Ну используйте вместо `strcpy` - вашу `kopir`. Только имеет смысл сделать ее статической. Еще - непонятен комментарий `// символ перевода строки, = \n`, ну а саму функцию я бы сократил до одной строки - `while (*first++ = *second++);` - если не нужна защита от дурака типа не нулевые ли указатели переданы... Ну, и фиксированный размер массива для строки тоже несколько смущает. Что будете делать, если пользователь введет слово в 90 символов?

Comment: А вам здесь вообще не нужно самому писать ни копирующий конструктор, ни копирующее присваивание. Компилятор сгенерирует их за вас.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,  и как  компилятор выполнит присвоение массивов? К тому же ему нужно просто менять массив на указатель

Comment: @ARHovsepyan *"и как компилятор выполнит присвоение массивов?"* Немного не понимаю вопрос. Просто присвоит каждому элементу одного массива соответствующий элемент другого. *"нужно просто менять массив на указатель"* Да, так было бы намного удобнее...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,  вот так и нужно  обьяснять. Будет понятнее для  незнающих. Я специально задал вопрос...

Comment: В задании требуется переопределить метод присваивания, но нельзя использовать strcpy, я решил, что можно сделать как-то как в kopir. Но у меня не получается это сделать, в силу того, что плохо пока разобрался с ссылками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
Stroka& Stroka::operator=(const Stroka& s)
{
    this->kopir(str, s.str);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: а можно и без  this, просто  kopir(str, s.str);

Comment: Если так переопределить присваивание, то выдается ошибка "аргумент типа const char *" не совместимы с параметром типа "char *".

Comment: @kornilcdima тип второго параметр метода? `kopir()` стоит поменять на `const char *` - во первых ошибка исчезнет, во вторых будет понятно что этот метод не собирается менять второй параметр.